# How do I find a character and look forward and back?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm attempting to use a regex in Notepad++ to replace a string. The data is roughly shaped like the following. Some contacts do not have a last name, others don't have a first name. All contacts are delimited by a semicolon (;) and all have an email address bookended by angle brackets.

```
LastName, FirstName - Unit <first.last@SomeDomain.com>; LastName, FirstName - Unit <first.last@SomeDomain.com>; LastName, FirstName - Unit <first.last@SomeDomain.com>; FirstName - Unit <first.last@SomeDomain.com>;  FirstName <first.last@SomeDomain.com>; LastName, FirstName - Unit <first.last@SomeDomain.com>; LastName - Unit <first.last@SomeDomain.com>; LastName, FirstName - Unit <first.last@SomeDomain.com>;
```

How do I match the @ symbol in the email and then look back to find the opening angle bracket and then forward to find  the closing angle bracket? I'm using Notepad++ to replace the email addresses with a string, like "XXX".

Comment: Try [`(?<=<)[^<]+@[^>]+(?=>)`](https://regex101.com/r/idGPNM/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [This pattern](https://regex101.com/r/EDKyKZ/13) to catch all the emails.

`<[^>]*>`

It matches the opening bracket and matches characters until it finds the closing bracket, then it matches that as well.

If you want to exclude the brackets from your match you can use this:

[`(?<=<)[^>]*(?=>)`](https://regex101.com/r/EDKyKZ/15)

Comment: I like it, nice and simple. I had a more complicated solution that matched on the beginning whitespace and opening bracket combination and the closing bracket. It failed occasionally and replaced way more than it should.

Answer (score 1):

For your given example, you could use a positive [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and positive lookahead to assert that what is on the left and right side are `<>`

To match the email part use a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to match not an opening bracket `[^<]+`, match an `@` and then use a negating character class to match not a closing bracket `[^>]+`

[`(?<=<)[^<]+@[^>]+(?=>)`](https://regex101.com/r/idGPNM/1)

To match including the opening and closing brackets and the semicolon you could use:

[`<[^<]+@[^>]+>;`](https://regex101.com/r/XvlnVQ/1)

Comment: This seems unnecessary if they just want to replace the email with "xxx". Although, if they wanted to keep track of the first.last and domain separately this could be useful.

Comment: @emsimpson92 For the current example data that is correct. But this might be part of a larger dataset and it is about an email address so my suggestion would be to match an `@` sign as well.

Comment: That's true. I suppose there could be other fields encapsulated by `<>`

Answer (score 1):

A very fast and precise workaround would be:

```
<[^@\s<>]+@[^@\s<>]+>;
```

See [live demo here](https://regex101.com/r/JH3MuK/1)

Breakdown:

- `<` Match opening angle bracket
- `[^@\s<>]+` Match any thing but `@`, a whitespace, `>` or `<`
- `@` Match a `@`
- `[^@\s<>]+` Repeat same character class as above
- `>;` Match closing angle bracket following a `;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following regex:

```
[^<]+@[^>]+
```

If you are sure that the first and last names aren't going to contain *@ and angled brackets*, then the above regex would work fine. It saves the performance overhead caused by lookaheads and lookbehinds.

Comment: While we're on the subject of performance, this took 3287 steps to match. `(?<=<)[^>]*(?=>)` takes 487 and `<[^>]*>` takes 32.

Comment: And the fourth bird's solution took 791

Comment: What about the time it takes to replace all the emails in a string? (I have checked it, and `[^<]+@[^>]+` comes out to be faster)

Comment: `<[^>]*>` is the fastest, but it matches the angled brackets. I am comparing `[^<]+@[^>]+` to the regexes that donot match brackets.